# What is the difference between "a shared problem" and "a problem shared"

Tags: syntax

An English proverb is "a problem shared is a problem halved". What is the difference between " a problem shared" and "a shared problem"?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

"A problem shared" has the passive participle modifying the noun "problem".  As participles are verbs, they have (implied) subjects and objects.  So this using this implies the existence of "someone doing the sharing".  It means that the proverb give advice that "You should share your problems".

If you said, "A shared problem",  that would remove the implication that "someone shared the problem" and it would just mean "if two people have the same problem ...". That would not be advice to share your problems.

Compare this with the similar proverb

> A penny saved is a penny gained.

Likewise this is giving advice to "save your pennies".

Answer (score 2):

The difference is:

In 'a problem shared', the participle 'shared', used as an adjective modifying the noun 'problem', is placed after the noun. 'Shared' is here a 'postmodifier'.

In 'a shared problem', the participle 'shared', used as an adjective modifying the noun 'problem', is placed before the noun. 'Shared' is here a 'premodifier'.

> The participles (present or past) can be used as adjectives to modify
> a noun or noun phrase. They can be placed before or after a noun. They
> are called premodifiers (before a noun) and postmodifiers (after a
> noun)

As a rule of thumb:

Put the modifier before the noun in most 'simple' cases.

Put modifiers after the noun when they are themselves part of a more complex phrase or clause.